# Running python scripts taking inputs from User in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, twitterapi-python

I'm using snscrape-the python module for collecting some tweets. So for that, I've created a Django framework, where the user will give the keyword dates as an input and the searching for tweets will begin. I've created a different python file for snscrape, so now I need to integrate it to django, but it's not working. Can anybody suggest me on how to do it. The file name is *starter.py*.

Comment: Please, provide more information along with the code.

Comment: the thing is we need to take inputs from user to query so that it is going to run after submitting

Comment: Are you using django forms for that?

Comment: not using anything we are in thought of using it
any suggestions of taking inputs from user

Comment: As it seems like a web app you can use the normal jinja template for web view and use Django forms for validation and taking the inputs.

Comment: any tutorial or please a provide a link showing whole process

Comment: It is not a complex thing. Just go through any Django tutorial to understand the process. If you are new to Django go through the Django tutorial on the official documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/

Comment: which topic i should surf?

Comment: Go through parts 3 and 4 first. If you have a problem understanding that go through the prior parts.